# Can I reload variable in a watch command?

Tags: shell, quoting, variable-substitution, watch

Part of my job involves some data handling. One of the tasks is to 'flatten' a set of directories (which we'll call *Dir* for now), and copy them to a new location called DirFlat.

This can take a long time (30 minutes ->2-3 hours)! I'd like to be able to watch the progress, so I use `find Dir -type f|wc -l` to get the number of files (lets call this `$Filenum`, and then I run a very short command that I wrote (retyping from my notebook, may have copied it wrong, I hope you get the gist):

`echo $(echo "($ls DirFlat |wc -l)*100/$FileNum"|bc) "%" $(date)`

However, if I run `watch -n 100 "!!"` it takes the output of the echo, and keeps printing that (even the date doesn't change).

Can I get this to refresh the variable/re-run the assignment of the internal variables in BASH? Hopefully this will help me in automating some of my tasks.

Comment: This really doesn't sound like the right process. There are good answers to your question here, but I think it's the wrong approach. This is a perfect opportunity to use `cron`. Cron will run a command regularly and then email you the output. Could you just have a script that cron runs? Something that would check if the process is running, and if it is running, email a status email? Have that run every 10 minutes or so. You only get emails when it's working. You don't have to run anything interactively. You don't tie up server resources by constantly piping data back to your terminal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Contrast:

```
$ watch -n 1 "echo $(date)"
Every 1.0s: echo Sat Apr 27 03:10:50 CEST 2013

$ watch -n 1 'echo $(date)'
Every 1.0s: echo $(date)
```

What you've done is to run `echo "($ls DirFlat |wc -l)*100/$FileNum"|bc` and `date`, substitute the output of each command into the shell command `watch -n 100 "echo $(…) % $(…)"`, and run that. You need to prevent the expansion of the command in the parent shell, and instead pass it as a string to `watch` for it to run. This is a simple matter of using single quotes around the command instead of double quotes.

Comment: I know SO comments are not for endorsements or personal resolutions, but man, I think now's a good time for me to sit down and re-learn shell from the ground-up.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can wrap it into a shell loop:

```shell
while sleep 100; do
    (... your stuff ...)
    if [ (... process has finished ...) ]; then
        (... beep or get operator's attention otherwise ...)
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: This is probably the behaviour I'm after! If I push this to the background, will it still output to the terminal?

Comment: Yes, but remember not to close the terminal.  Or better run it in a terminal multiplexer like `tmux` or `screen`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put this into a shell script and let watch call this script then.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: @Pureferret Example? `watch -n 100 /my/script.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

A while loop with the command you want to run and the sleep command will also allow you to run the linux command repeatedly like the watch command. Although, in this specific case @peterph's answer is better since it has a terminating condition. This shorter response only answers the question on how to refresh when re-running the same process.

```
while true; do echo $(date +"%T"); sleep 1; done
```

The number after sleep is in seconds.